# MySQL Insert Issue : #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, mysql-error-1136

> Im trying to input value of continous counting debit-kredit into saldo column, heres my sql code

> I want to do debit - kredit and put in saldo column, my query above allows me to retrieve saldo values but not failed on inserting

```
SET @variable = 0;
-- Without Pagination
INSERT into laporan_bukubesar (`saldo`)
SELECT        `tanggal`, `debit`, `kredit`, @variable := @variable + (`debit` - `kredit`) as `saldo`
FROM          laporan_bukubesar
ORDER BY      `tanggal` ASC;
```

> #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

[Heres my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CsyT.png)

[Heres what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRkvT.png)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ive update my question sir, thats what i want, but it only a view, i want to insert the value on saldo in my table

Comment: Your INSERT contains one column (`saldo`), into which you're trying to place multiple values. The error message says that pretty clearly with *column count doesn't match value count*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to *update* the value:

```
UPDATE laporan_bukubesar
    SET saldo = (@variable := @variable + (`debit` - `kredit`))
    ORDER BY tanggal ASC;
```

Comment: Its work sir, thaks for helping me, i just add SET @variable = 0; at the beginning
SET @variable = 0;
UPDATE laporan_bukubesar
    SET saldo = (@variable := @variable + (`debit` - `kredit`))
    ORDER BY tanggal ASC;